# Copy conditional formatting rule from Excel with openpyxl

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting, copy, openpyxl

**SOLUTION:** I solved it using type "num" instead of percentile. Here is the working code:

```
rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='num', start_value=0, start_color='FF0000',
                        mid_type='num', mid_value=0.5, mid_color='FFD966',
                        end_type='num', end_value=1, end_color='00B050')
newsheet.conditional_formatting.add("B12", rule)
```

**Original Question:**

I'm trying to copy a cell in excel from one worksheet to another one. The cell contains percentages and has a conditional formatting rule applied, but it gets lost somehow.

So I tried formatting it with openpyxl(master is the original sheet, newsheet the new sheet):

```
        newsheet["B12"] = master["C" + str(i)].value
        rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=0, start_color='FF0000FF',
                              mid_type='percentile', mid_value=50, mid_color='FFD966FF',
                              end_type='percentile', end_value=100, end_color='FF00B050')
        newsheet.conditional_formatting.add("B12", rule)
```

For some reason the color is the same no matter what percentage value is in the cell. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating Conditional Formatting with 'Graded Color Scale' and applying it to a single cell.
Therefore there is no `low, medium and high` value. There is just the one value which I believe defaults to high, the `FF00B050` [green] colour, for any value entered in the cell.

Set the range of the CF to at least 2 cells to see some colour variation, when the two cells have different values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's also what I think is happening. I think openpyxl has 'min' and 'max'  types for that but I am using 'percentile', which I thought would give me what I want. Neither min/max nor percentile does what I want. I have it working in Excel with the rule creator but I'm unsure how to do it with openpyxl.